# Vexflow 5 string banjo

Tags: typescript, vexflow

I have been working with vexflow to make guitar tabs, but want to use it for a 5 string banjo. I can see there is a banjo setting in the Tuning, which does work, but it still prints 6 strings in tab. Is there anyway to make it show just the 5 strings?

```
tabstave notation=true key=C tuning=standardBanjo

notes 1-2-1-3/1|1-1-2-2/1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the number of lines (strings) using the [`StaveOptions.num_lines`](https://0xfe.github.io/vexflow/api/interfaces/StaveOptions.html#num_lines) property

```ts
const stave = new TabStave(10, 40, 400, { num_lines: 5 });

// or

system.addStave({
  voices: [...],
  options: { num_lines: 5 },
})
```